# In Tableau: Adding a row on the sheet which is independent on the column but depend on the row.Need a Total on the columns data as a separate row

Tags: tableau-api

I am sorry, I don't know how to frame  my question in the heading. Plz look at the link for understanding.
Data and format of the tableau are in the below link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CbvShvcKT8v2t8ixub72f2ZPCExvDaJZw0uYVlt4XW8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create a report like this using Exclude LOD expression ,only the position of Total field is different in the solution.
[**Solution**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJkwQ.png)

**Calulated Columns:**

**Col:**
if [Rating Logic] ="0" then "PricingNoRL"
elseif [Rating Logic] ="1" then "PricingRL"
else "other"
END

**PricingNoRL:**
if [Col]="PricingNoRL" then 1 else 0 end

**PricingRL:**
if [Col]="PricingRL" then 1 else 0 end

**Other:**
if [Col]="other" then 1 else 0 end

**%RL :**
sum([PricingRL])/(sum([PricingRL])+sum([PricingNoRL]))

**Total:**
{exclude [Request Type] :sum([Number of Records])}

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Meenakshi , Followed your steps and I got partial results .I have updated Google sheets , the way reports should look like , I needed the Grand Total of all rows . While adding Totals getting for requestType cols but not for total . Could you have a look  please